# Async function call in python

Tags: python, multithreading

In python I want to create an async method in a class that create a thread without blocking the main thread. When the new thread finish, I return a value from that function/thread.

For example the class is used for retrieve some information from web pages. I want run parallel processing in a function that download the page and return a object.

```
class WebDown:
    def display(self, url):
        print 'display(): ' + content

    def download(self, url):
        thread = Thread(target=self.get_info)
        # thread join
        print 'download(): ' + content
        # return the info

    def get_info(self, url):
        # download page
        # retrieve info
        return info

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wd = WebDown()
    ret = wd.download('http://...')
    wd.display('http://...')
```

I this example, in order I call download() for retrieve the info, after display() for print others information. The print output should be

```
display(): foo, bar, ....
download(): blue, red, ....
```

Comment: have you tried the threading module in python?

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to use threading module for call async method

Comment: you want to create a method that does the calls async?

Comment: yes, call another method async with thread and when the thread is completed, return the value

Comment: @NaN Did you try Googling "python threading example? There are thousands of examples that would show you how to do this. [Here's one from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies), for example.

Comment: Look into using Twisted, it has examples for asynchronously fetching web pages.

Answer (score 1):

One way to write asynchronous, non blocking code in python involves using Python's Twisted. Twisted does not rely on [multithreading but uses multiprocessing instead](http://krondo.com/?p=1209). It gives you convenient way to create Deferred objects, adding callbacks and errbacks to them. The example you give would look like this in Twisted, I'm using [treq](https://github.com/dreid/treq) (Twisted Requests) library which makes generating requests a little quicker and easier:

```
from treq import get
from twisted.internet import reactor

class WebAsync(object):
    def download(self, url):
        request = get(url)
        request.addCallback(self.deliver_body)

    def deliver_body(self, response):
        deferred = response.text()
        deferred.addCallback(self.display)
        return deferred

    def display(self, response_body):
        print response_body
        reactor.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web_client = WebAsync()
    web_client.download("http://httpbin.org/html")
    reactor.run()
```

Both 'download' and 'deliver_body' methods return [deferreds](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/core/howto/defer.html), you add callbacks to them that are going to be executed when results is available.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use [request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) called [grequests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests).

```
import grequests
>>> urls = [
    'http://...',
    'http://...'
]
>>> rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
>>> grequests.map(rs)
[<Response [200]>, <Response [200]>]
```